# Spring JPA creates new record instead of updating existing record

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using standard Spring CrudRepository.  When attempting to update a record, a new record is created instead even though the primary key is assigned a non-null value.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Timothy

**Software versions**

- Spring boot 2.4.0
- Database postgres 9.6.17

**Entity to be saved**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dc_motor")
public class DcMotor implements Serializable, DatabaseEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4015060163435939638L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Version
    private Integer version;
    // other fields here
    // does NOT define equals() nor hashCode()
}
```

**save method in service tier**

```
@Override
    public DcMotorRest saveMotor(DcMotorRest motorToBeSaved) throws MotorNotFoundException {
        if (motorToBeSaved.getId() != null) {

            Optional<DcMotor> motor = dcRepo.findById(motorToBeSaved.getId());

            if (!motor.isPresent())
                throw new MotorNotFoundException(
                        "DC Motor with ID [%d] not found.  Unable to update.  Use empty / null id to create a new DC Motor"
                                .formatted(motorToBeSaved.getId()));
        }

        // troubleshooting code
        DcMotor t = new DcMotor(motorToBeSaved);
        if (t.getId() == null) {
            logger.debug("ID is null in motor to be saved");
        } else {
            logger.debug("ID is [{}] in motor to be saved", t.getId());
        }
        DcMotor savedMotor = dcRepo.save(t);    // dcRepo extends CrudRepository<DcMotor, Long>

        // DcMotor savedMotor = new DcMotor(motorToBeSaved);

        return new ModelMapper().map(savedMotor, DcMotorRest.class);
    }
```

**Log output**

```
  DEBUG 7868 --- [nio-8070-exec-1] c.e.s.w.service.impl.DcMotorServiceImpl  : ID is [2333] in motor to be saved
  DEBUG 7868 --- [nio-8070-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : insert into dc_motor ( ...) values (...)
```

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `DcMotor`, and you are not showing us code for the constructor you are using. Please make sure `t` has Id after this line: `DcMotor t = new DcMotor(motorToBeSaved);`

Comment: Thanks for reviewing! The log statement just below the new outputs "null" or the id. In this case, it is the value 2333. Yet the SQL logged is an insert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to use

```
var inDb = dcRepo.findOne(motorToBeSaved.getId());
```

update that instance and then call

```
dcRepo.save(inDb);
```

An alternative is to use `EntityManager` https://stackoverflow.com/a/62925149/14072498

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the problem is here:

```
DcMotor t = new DcMotor(motorToBeSaved);
```

Basically it's an object you create, Hibernate doesn't know about it so it's considered as a new object. You need to first find that entity in the database, update it and then save.